# Octave/MatLab: Import Lines From a CSV File According to Whether Column Matches Condition

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io, octave

I have a large CSV file with customer data all in numerical format, and my program begins with:

```
customerData = csvread('CTData.csv');
```

However, the file is by now far too large for my 32-bit build of Octave for Windows to load directly; moreover, it is too large to manually modify so that all the data is numeric.

So instead of loading the file directly, I'd like to first create a new file *CTData6mo.csv* which extracts a properly formatted 6-month subset of the data.

The format of the CSV file is:

```
Business Unit | Date | Customer ID | data 1 | ... | data 19 | Description
```

where the *data j* (*j=1,2,...,19*) are customer data of interest.

The format of *Business Unit* and *Description* entries are strings, and I'd like them to be deleted in the new import file so that column 1 = *Date*.  The format of the Date is short date: *mm/dd/yyyy*

I'd like to create two variables *beginDate* and *endDate* which correspond to the beginning and end of the six month time period of interest, and imagining going line-by-line checking whether the date (column 2) of the kth row is within the desired range or not; if so, then write that row to the new import file with the first (1) and last (23) columns deleted.

I'm not particularly well-versed with Octave's file I/O methods or methods for handling dates, so some guidance implementing the method described in the above paragraph or offering a more efficient implementation would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

This is the implementation that I came up with:

```
dBegin = datenum('12/01/2013');
dEnd = datenum('05/30/2014');
fName1 = 'CT_no_weekends.csv';
fName2 = 'CTData.csv';
fID1 = fopen(fName1, 'r');
fID2 = fopen(fName2, 'w');
fprintf(fID2, '%s', strjoin(strtok(strsplit(fgetl(fID1), ','), '"'), ','));
while ~feof(fID1)
  csvLineString = fgetl(fID1);
  csvLineArray = strtok(strsplit(csvLineString, ','), '"');
  csvLineArray{2} = datenum(csvLineArray{2}, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
  if (csvLineArray{2} <= dEnd && csvLineArray{2} >= dBegin)
    csvLineArray(:, length(csvLineArray)) = [];
    csvLineArray(:, 1) = [];
    fpritnf(fID2, '%s', strjoin(cellfun(@num2str, csvLineArray, 'UniformOutput', 0), ','));
  endif
endwhile
```

Comment: Please add a few lines of example of the `CTData.csv` to show us what they look like exactly, and also the corresponding few lines that you would like in the output file. also let us now if octave has the [`textscan`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) function (read the doc if yes). You can also read a bit on [`fscanf`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html)

Comment: @Hoki Octave has textscan implemented, yes.  See my edit for my implementation.  The loop takes quite awhile to finish, so I'm hoping there is a pre-existing method that is more efficient.  But otherwise, I can live with this.

Comment: Is there a way to set the next line to be read at the first instance of dBegin in column 2?  This would speed up the loop considerably since the data is sorted chronologically, particularly if dBegin is toward the end of the range.

Comment: @Andy gave you an answer (which make sense) to that in your former question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827838/position-file-pointer-to-first-instance-of-a-value-in-a-csv-file