# Octave/Matlab - Optimizing CSV Import - Speeding Up datenum

Tags: matlab, csv, optimization, file-io, octave

I've been having a lot of frustration with importing CSV files in Octave.

This is my latest implementation below.  The format of the CSV file is:

```
"Business Unit" | "Date" | "Customer ID" | data 1 | ... | data 19 | "Description"
```

where the *data j* (*j=1,2,...,19*) are customer data of interest.

I want to extract a subset of the rows based on whether the corresponding date falls within the range dBegin and dEnd, and then output the subset to a new file extractedData.csv with the Business Unit and Description removed.

The implementation I had before was a line-by-line loop, checking each row for the date condition.  However, it was far too slow.  So I took a suggestion to load the data in pieces to speed up the process.  The file is over a million rows long (about 1gb) and even this implementation is taking forever (as of this writing it still has not finished after 15 minutes, and I tested it on a smaller file first to make sure it works).

Some advice would be appreciated!  One thing I can't understand yet is how R manages to import the data so quickly all at once without crashing (i.e. `data_set = read.table("rawData.csv", sep=",")` works as expected in R, yet the equivalent in Octave promptly crashes due to lack of memory, thus forcing me into a more manual implementation like the one below).  I'm using 32-bit builds for both.

```
    dBegin = datenum('12/01/2013');
    dEnd = datenum('05/30/2014');
    fName1 = 'rawData.csv';
    fName2 = 'extractedData.csv';
    fID1 = fopen(fName1, 'r');
    fID2 = fopen(fName2, 'w');
    formatSpec = '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s'; % load everything as a string
    headerString = strjoin(strtok(strsplit(fgetl(fID1), ','), '"'), ','); % read first row with header information
    fprintf(fID2, '%s', headerString); % output headers to new file
    N = 100000; % we'll read N rows at a time
    while ~feof(fID1)
      C = textscan(fID1, formatSpec, N, 'Delimiter', ','); % read a block of N rows
      dateVector = datenum(strtok(C{1,2}, '"')); % convert the short date strings in column 2 into numerical values
      indexVector = find(dateVector >= dBegin & dateVector <= dEnd); % determine which rows fall in the correct date range
      if (length(indexVector) == 0)
        continue; % read the next block of data if there are no matching dates
      endif
      D = num2str(datenum(C{1,2}(indexVector,1))); % Create a new cell array with first column as dates (in numerical format)
      for i = 2:19
        D(:, i) = C{1,i+1}(indexVector, 1); % append all of the other corresponding columns to each row
      endfor
      for i = 1:length(indexVector) % print D row-by-row to the new file
        fprintf(fID2, '%s\n', strjoin(strtok(D(i, :), '"'), ',')); % cellfun(@num2str, D, 'UniformOutput', 0)
      endfor
    endwhile
    fclose(fID1);
    fclose(fID2);
```

**EDIT**

After debugging, I noticed that that this line is taking a significant amount of time to execute relative to the others:

```
dateVector = datenum(strtok(C{1,2}, '"'));
```

And replacing the above line with

```
C{1,2} = strtok(C{1,2}, '"');
dateVector = datenum(C{1,2});
```

shows it is the call to datenum that slows up the program.  Are there any ways to fix this?

Comment: See the question growing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825530/octave-matlab-import-lines-from-a-csv-file-according-to-whether-column-matches https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827838/position-file-pointer-to-first-instance-of-a-value-in-a-csv-file

Comment: Make a function which does only one thing: find the line where dBegin is (may be try to compare the string without call to datenum to save conversion time). Once you know which line it is, call `textscan` with the parameter `headerlines`.

Comment: Okay - so I've devised a method to get the first line at which m = dBegin is found and the last line on which n = dEnd is found.  How do I tell textscan to read this range?  I could of course put N := m - n, but I'm not sure how to set the file pointer at line m.